# How to redirect to the Startup object detail after the user updates/deletes/creates a Post (or cancels in either of the 3 cases)

Tags: django, redirect

To use the Django Unleashed example, suppose the user is on a Startup detail page and starts to create a Post, then decides to cancel. If I wanted the cancel button to redirect to a Startup list, that's easy:

href="{% url 'organizer_startup_list' %}" class="button button-primary"> Cancel

...but the user expects it to redirect to the Startup detail. 
Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using Class Based Views on django.

and You want to deliver another `context` through your views.

Solution: override `get_context_data`.

this is simple example:

```
class OrderDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'order/order_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['region_list'] = Region.objects.all()
        return context
```

This DetailViews originally provide `Order` object, but when you override `get_context_data`, you can add your own `context` with `context['your_context_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Beomi - Thanks.
I muddied the question. The question is after the user commits the create (or cancels), how to redirect to the Startup detail (Post has a ForeignKey pointing to Startup) ? The scenario is the user starts to write a post (blog) about this Startup instance, then commits or maybe bails out. He/she expects it to go back to that Startup detail.

from django.views.generic import CreateView

class PostCreate(PostFormValidMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostFormValidMixin:
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(self.request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            self.get_success_url())

form
          action=" url 'blog_post_create' "
          method="post"
         csrf_token 
         form.as_p 
        href="{% url '???' %}" class="button button-primary" Cancel
        button
            class="button-primary"
            type="submit"
          Create Blog Post /button
      /form

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase the question. In Django Unleashed, he redirects to the Post list page after a successful Post delete (see code below). Suppose Post had a ForeignKey pointing to Startup (instead of a ManyToMany) and you wanted to redirect to the Startup detail after a successful delete (what the user would expect). The problem is you don't have access to the slug or pk of the Startup that the user is creating,updating, or deleting posts about.

```
class PostDelete(DateObjectMixin, DeleteView):
    date_field = 'pub_date'
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_post_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

Distilled the question:

https://github.com/jambonrose/DjangoUnleashed-1.8/commit/f6b11ed351

This is the html for creating a Post (blog).
I want to add  a cancel button and I want both submit and cancel to redirect to the Startup detail page that the user was on when they decided to blog about that particular Startup (Post has a ForeignKey pointing to Startup, which is in a different app).
Thanks for your patience.